# how to disable dragend animation in html5

Tags: html, drag

I created a draggable element by setting its `draggable` attribute. When I drop the element, there is an animation of the element snapping back to its origin position:

[image: snap-back animation]

How can the snap-back animation be disabled? I tried calling `preventDefault()` on the dragend event, but it had no effect on the animation.

The following snippet shows the basics:

```js
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener(
    'dragend', evt => {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
);
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

#test {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="test" draggable='true'></div>
</div>
```

Not every browser will show the dragged `#test` jumping back to the original position.

Comment: ![here is the demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utuhj.gif)

Answer (score 21):

In order to prevent the animation, you need the `drop` event to fire. For the `drop` event to fire, you need to call `preventDefault()` in the handler for `dragover`.

```
document.addEventListener('dragover', function(e) { e.preventDefault() })
```

Example in MDN docs shows the same thing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drop#Example

An old blog post describing the quirks of HTML5 Drag and Drop API: https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/09/the_html5_drag.html

Comment: Can you please show a working example of this?

Comment: This has to be done on any parent of the draggable

Answer (score 0):

As was said earlier, you need to explicitly describe `onDragOver` handler on the **parent's container** (where you will drop your `draggable` element) and put `.preventDefault()` on event to prevent this animation.

Here is a simple **React** code example for better understanding of this mechanic (you can **position** the box inside the container **by dragging** it):

[image: Drag and drop app example]

***App.jsx***

```
import './App.css'

const App = () => {
    function handleDragOver(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
    }

    function handleDrop(e) {
        let box = document.getElementById('box')

        if (box) {
            box.style.top = e.clientY + 'px'
            box.style.left = e.clientX + 'px'
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="container" onDragOver={handleDragOver} onDrop={handleDrop}>
            <div id="box" draggable></div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

***App.css***

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}

#box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    position: absolute;
}
```