# Can you disable the delay/animation when cancelling a native drag event?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, drag-and-drop

While a drag event is occurring, if you drop the element in a droppable area the handler activates immediately. However, if you're over a non-droppable area, or cancel by pressing escape, there's a brief delay as the preview returns to the original spot. However, if you have the preview hidden then you want the drag cancel immediately.

One solution is to make everything a droppable area, but this only solves the problem of dropping outside the intended area, as cancelling will still be delayed.

I recognize that only modifier keys are accepted during a drag, overriding listening for a keydown. I've also seen this question: [how to disable dragend animation in html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42991709/how-to-disable-dragend-animation-in-html5)

Does one have to use a library, or build a custom drag solution using only pointer events?